# Why am I getting password field required?

Tags: php, laravel

this is the **form**

```html
<form class="signup-form" action="{{route('signup')}}" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="{{old('name')}}">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="{{old('email')}}">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="Confirm Password">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
    <button type="submit" name="button">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

this is the **route**

```php
Route::get('home/registration', 'authController@showRegisterForm')->name('signup');
Route::post('home/registration', 'authController@register');
```

this is the **controller**

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use app\User;

class authController extends Controller
{
    public function showRegisterForm() {
        return view('registration');
    }

    public function register(Request $request) {
        $this->validation($request);
        return $request->all();
    }

    public function validation($request) {
        return $this->validate($request, [
            'name'=>'required|max:255',
            'email'=>'required|email|unique:users|max:255',
            'passsword'=>'required|confirmed|max:255',
        ]); 
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error after putting the validation in the controller. I have checked all the values are coming through the request before putting validation but after I put validation it's showing that the password field is required even though I'm entering the password.

Comment: There is a typo on your validation, passsword with 3 's'... could this be causing the problem?

Comment: @LucasArbex yes that was the problem, fixed, many many thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Request method for validation:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#form-request-validation

Answer (score 0):

There is a password spelling mistake on your function validation.